# Send WhatsApp Message out of another application in android. Without opening WhatsApp

Tags: java, android, message, whatsapp

my question is, if it is possible to send a whats app message out of an android application, without opening WhatsApp.
I already know that i can do something like share and then WhatsApp opens and i have to press send again. But i want to send it automatically out of another application.Without any further user interaction.
Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Dont think whatsapp  would allow it..

Comment: If you're trying to make an app like WhatsApp Plus, you should know that WhasApp Plus isn't an app that works alongside the original WhatsApp app. It's a modified version of WhatsApp itself and has features built on top of it. There is no concept of "controlling" an app using another app, that is done using Intents which are handled by applications themselves so it requires them to be invoked.

Answer (score 2):

Fast and short: No, that's not possible.

Even the webapplication of whatsapp (web.whatsapp.com) needs your phone online permanently with a running whatsapp-'app'.

Answer (score 1):

No You cant. Every application is independent on its own. Even when you're sharing some content via whatsapp what's actually happening is that we're just providing whatsapp an intent with your data. The rest of it is actually took care by whatsapp itself, i.e, what to do with that data.

Answer (score 1):

This breaks the Whatsapp ToS. 
The whatsapp faq says this:

> Be aware that the following actions are in violation of our Terms of
>   Service:
>
> Using an automated system or an unauthorized / unofficial client
>   application to send messages through WhatsApp.

The only (legal) way would be to use the [sharing method](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/28000012) you mentioned, which works through custom url schemes, and this requires user interaction.

There is an app called [Whatsapp Scheduler](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=infinitylabs.com.whatsappscheduler), but looking at the reviews that no longer seems to work, probably because it violated the ToS.